# Shipping a pom.xml that says the jar includes the dependencies

Tags: maven, ant, dependencies, pom.xml, sonatype

I have an open source project that uses Apache Commons IO dependencies.

I don't use Maven for build, only Ant, and the final `jar` contains Apache Commons IO dependencies: purpose is that users don't need to set `CLASSPATH`.
So the binary release contains only *one* `jar`. Let's say it's name is `project-1.0.jar`.

Now I want to include my project in Maven Central.

I create a `pom.xml` with the Commons IO dependencies required for compilation:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

And I send to Sonatype the `project-1.0.jar`,  `project-1.0-sources.jar` and  `project-1.0-javadoc.jar`, as usually.

How can I declare in the `pom.xml` that `project-1.0.jar` ***already*** contains the dependencies?

Is it possible/legal to do it this way?
If not, what are the others options?

(I would like to keep the same build for Maven users and non-Maven users, to simplify builds, tests and maintenance.)

Thanks,
Nico

Comment: Just don't do that. Your jar should contain your classes, and your classes only. I, as a user, might need to use another version of commons-io with your library. I'm not even sure you are allowed to redistribute commons-io in your own library on Maven Central. The whole point of Maven is to set the classpath for you. So setting the classpath, for a developer, using Maven, is a non-issue.

Comment: Thank you, this is very convincing. Can you publish that as an answer?

Comment: If you really had a use case for this where you were somehow wire-tied to a specific version of a third party library like that, it might make sense to re-package and internalize that library into your own source code.  Prefix all their packages with your own and drop the source into your project's source tree.

Comment: @David, thanks, but this is not my question.

Answer (score 0):

See [POM Reference, Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies):

> - **scope:**
>     ...
>
>   - ...
>   - **provided** - this is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide it at runtime. It is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.
>   - ...

Answer (score 0):

In this simple case just use define commons-io as a dependency that's it. The rest will be handled by maven. I can recommend you start using Maven as well would make your life easier as well.